# How to get access to half-open subscription-only data?

Tags: data-request

The IMF and other organizations have public data by subscription. Some university libraries have CDs from these vendors or online subscription.

Are there any online libraries that provide similar temporary access to these datasets?

Answer (score 4):

I can't speak for other libraries, but at the university library where I work at in the United States...

If we had a CD copy of this, you would need to get an account with us (which would cost $25 and be restricted to residents of the state) to be able to check it out.

If we had online access to this, you'd need to come by in person to one of our libraries and use one of the guest computers. Typically we allow guests access for an hour a day but for folks doing research, we'd gladly extend that time if their research intent was made clear. Folks not affiliated with the university can't get off-site access to our electronic subscriptions per our contracts with the vendors.